# How do I pass a 2D Array from Swift to Objective-C?

Tags: arrays, swift, objective-c

I have a function written in Objective C:

```objectivec
- (UInt8*) some_function: (UInt8[][5]) input originalSize: (UInt8[]) size;
```

I need to pass a 2D array from Swift to the Objective-C function above. I have tried passing a 2D array in Swift by prefixing the `&` operator, but I get a build-time error:

> `Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<[UInt8]>' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<(UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8, UInt8)>'`.

I am new to Objective-C and I have no idea how to properly pass a 2D array to the function. What am I doing wrong and how do I do it properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're not using `NSArray`?

Comment: It sounds like you need to pass a **C** 2D array from Swift to ObjectiveC. Swift Arrays are most similar to Objective-C NSArrays. C arrays have to be handled as unsafe pointers in Swift.

Comment: @DuncanC Yes, that is correct. Is there a way to do that or do I have to use NSArray?

Comment: @Alexander No, there is no reason. Should I be using `NSArray`?

Comment: When your API is imported to Swift, the compiler will automatically generate code to bridge your NSArrays to native Swift arrays, which makes them substantially easier to work with.

Comment: @Alexander Sorry, I was wrong, I do need to use C arrays. Is there a way to do it without NSArray?

Comment: Yeah, but it's more complicated. Depending on your performance needs, you might still have an easier time converting your C arrays to NSArray in Objective C, and having those import to Swift as native Swift arrays. Otherwise you'll have to fiddle with the UnsafePointer APIs on the Swift side, which are quick a bit trickier and more dangerous.

Comment: Can you provide an example of passing a Swift 2D array to an Objective C function as a C 2D array?

Comment: in C arrays are different from C++. Basically in C you have to know the starting pointer of the first entry of a data block, which is what you pass around and also pass the length separately because C takes the length you say it is. Using NSArray or similar is just convenience not to hande the length and type of the content. Don't be afraid of unsafePointers in swift, they just sound martial.. in fact they are just pointers.

Comment: So when you know how to pass a pointer, you also know how to pass an C array.
As soon you write something like `UInt8[][5]` it looks like C but is C++. Better use `UInt8 *` in exchange and pass the length as extra parameter.